Getting the same output over and over again for regression model
My regression model is related to a self driving car, and the data consists of magnitudes of 5 sensors and a turning angle as an output.
DataParser.Parse(out double[][] input, out double[] output,"data.csv", (0, 4), (4, 5));
var model = new FanChenLinSupportVectorRegression<Gaussian>();
var svm = model.Learn(input, output);

Console.WriteLine(svm.Score(new double[] { 95.0, 0.0, 67.8, 0.0, 0.0 }));

I have decided to experiment to see if the FanChenLin regression algorithm works.
Now, the problem im facing is that for the output, I'm getting a constant value of 217.88. I have generated a mockup training data which might be wrong but I expect it to give different outputs when I give different inputs, but here, despite changing the outputs I'm still getting the 217.88 value.
The data parser I wrote seems to be getting the correct inputs and outputs.
I couldn't figure out what is going wrong.
I tried to change values such as complexity but although they give a different output, that output is still constant over different inputs.
37.454011884736246,3.142918568673425,64.20316461542878,5.16817211686077,10.31238688359326,21.365509618766623
95.07143064099162,63.64104112637804,8.413996499504883,53.1354631568148,90.25529066795667,61.22639465322385
73.1993941811405,31.435598107632668,16.162871409461378,54.06351216101065,50.525237244785714,0.16392599623276283
59.86584841970366,50.85706911647028,89.85541885270793,63.742990149820656,82.64574661077417,338.3506582186952
15.601864044243651,90.7566473926093,60.642905965958995,72.60913337226616,32.00496010306117,1.6476821446117356
15.599452033620265,24.929222914887493,0.9197051616629648,97.58520794625346,89.55232284962005,270.35942257808824
5.8083612168199465,41.038292303562976,10.147154286603211,51.630034830119534,38.92016787341631,283.0714170955975
86.61761457749351,75.55511385430486,66.35017691080559,32.2956472941246,1.083765148029836,62.743931568541655
60.11150117432088,22.879816549162246,0.5061583846218687,79.51861947687037,90.53819764192636,270.3330873043567
70.80725777960456,7.697990982879299,16.080805141749867,27.083225126207424,9.128667678613356,69.18216523195599
2.0584494295802447,28.9751452913768,54.87337893665861,43.89714207056361,31.93136375904149,320.77412786375123
96.99098521619943,16.122128725400444,69.18951976926932,7.845638134226595,95.0061967050805,8.435865969658153
83.24426408004217,92.96976523425731,65.19612595026005,2.535074341545751,95.06071469375561,50.33193776194861
21.233911067827616,80.8120379564417,22.42693094605598,96.26484146779251,57.34378881232861,293.50639083221773
18.182496720710063,63.34037565104234,71.2179221347536,83.59801205122058,63.183721216979926,317.50014925812815
18.34045098534338,87.14605901877177,23.724908749680008,69.59742060936979,44.84455219783198,339.3199373713304
30.42422429595377,80.36720768991145,32.539969815926774,40.89529444142699,29.321077169806454,51.271442802352
52.475643163223786,18.657005888603585,74.64914051180241,17.329432007084577,32.8664545369916,15.667156378272637
43.194501864211574,89.25589984899777,64.96328990472146,15.643704267108605,67.25184560770384,37.33686449574435
29.122914019804192,53.93422419156507,84.9223410494178,25.024289816459532,75.237452943768,348.5473288270272
61.18528947223795,80.74401551640625,65.76128923003434,54.92266647061205,79.15790437258485,6.806163770302646
13.949386065204184,89.60912999234932,56.830860333547164,71.45959227000624,78.96181427945538,320.4909103298581
29.214464853521815,31.800347497186387,9.367476782809248,66.01973767177313,9.120610304869036,303.55070797479505

